# How to read JXL Excel Sheet Rows and columns

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I have iterated rows and columns from reading excel but show `Arrayindexoutofbound` exception. I have given my code and error below

**Code :**

```
for (int i = 0; i <= wb.getSheet(0).getRows(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= wb.getSheet(0).getColumns(); j++) {
        String testData = wb.getSheet(0).getCell(i, j).getContents();
        System.out.println(testData);
    }
}
```

**Stackrace**

```
 User id
    en0063
    en0070
    Psw 
    en0063
    THEROCKZ1
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
        at jxl.read.biff.SheetImpl.getCell(SheetImpl.java:356)
        at ExcelRead.main(ExcelRead.java:29)
```

**Excel Image**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exceeding the number of rows and columns due to you for statments - change `<=` to `<`

```
for (int i = 0; i < wb.getSheet(0).getRows(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < wb.getSheet(0).getColumns(); j++) {
            String testData = wb.getSheet(0).getCell(i, j).getContents();
            System.out.println(testData);
        }
}
```

By the way it would be a lot easier to read if you stored you `sheet` in a variable such as

```
Sheet firstSheet = wb.getSheet(0);
```

and re-use it as

```
for (int i = 0; i < firstSheet.getRows(); i++) {   
// etc
```

**edit**

I suggest that you print out the number of rows and cells, as it seems that the library you are using seems to include blank ones as well.  Maybe you need to test for that.

Consider that you could have something like

```
X X X
X X X
X X X X
```

Comment: user id- en0063
PSW- en0063
User id
en0063
Psw 
en0063
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at jxl.read.biff.SheetImpl.getCell(SheetImpl.java:356)
 at ReadExcel.redExcel(ReadExcel.java:39)
 at Login.main(Login.java:28)
Still i get the same error